# Using Susy, how can I make a div expand to height of tallest sibling?

Tags: css, sass, susy

In susyless CSS, I could make containers with various content lengths grow to the height of of their tallest sibling using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.

```
.not-susy {
  .short {
    width: calc(100%/12 * 8);
  }
  .wrap{
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 20px;
  }
  .item {
    margin: 5px;
    display: table-cell;
  }
}
```

However this trick isn't working with Susy; How can I acheieve this same layout trick with Susy?

[Meister](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/a2feba5a4084f3d5559ac451d8490c47)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using the `span()` **mixin**, which is based around `display: float`. Instead, try using your usual technique, and only apply the `span()` **function** to set your width:

```
.susy {
  .short {
    width: span(8 of 12);
  }
  .wrap{
    display: table;
    border-spacing: gutter();
  }
  .item {
    margin: 5px;
    display: table-cell;
  }
}
```

I also used Susy's `gutter()` function to set the border-spacing. The `span()` and `gutter()` functions are the best part of Susy, because you can apply them to any property, and stay in control of everything else.

Comment: hey that works really nicely. thanks for the support!